# Constantly damped pendulum

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

The drag force in a damped pendulum is often assumed to be either linear (viscous drag) or quadratic (air drag). However, there is another case where I have failed to find any analysis.

If we have a pendulum on an inclined plane, there is a constant force between the bob and the plane which creates a drag force acting in the direction opposite to movement. The drag force is proportional to the bob mass, gravitational acceleration and the friction coefficient, but not velocity.

Ignoring the other drag forces and assuming the displacement is small, the differential equation becomes:

$$
\ddot{x} = - k_1x - k_2sgn(\dot{x})
$$

Is there an analytical solution to this system? The sgn certainly seems very inconvenient, but how does it influence the resulting function's continuity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can produce a piecewise analytical solution. Suppose $\dot x(0) > 0$. Solve $\ddot x = -k_1 x - k_2$ and find the time when $\dot x = 0$. Then solve $\ddot x = -k_1 x + k_2$ for the next part of the motion, and repeat.

There will only be a finite number of oscillations before all the energy is dissipated and the pendulum stops.